# How does Scala define a type of return value?

Tags: scala

How does Scala define a type of return value?

```
def sqrt = (x: Int) =>
  if (x > 0 && x < 4)
    x * x
```

The return type for my code is `Int => AnyVal`. But if I change it to

```
def method = (x: String) =>
  if (x.equals("abc"))
    x.concat(x)
```

The return type would be `String => Any`. But why not `AnyRef`? String is an object, so it is better to use `AnyRef`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your `if` expression has no else, `Unit` is returned if the condition evaluates to false. `Unit` extends `AnyVal` like `Int`, so in the first case the most specific type is `AnyVal`. Since `String` extends `AnyRef`, the most specific type is `Any` in the second case.